# Completely disable a keyboard shortcut for one application

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, remote-desktop

When using Microsoft Remote Desktop, I frequently find myself accidentally trying to close browser tabs with ⌘W (which is mapped to "Close Connection" by default).  I was at least able to stop it from closing the connection every time by mapping it to one of the help menu options, but it's still annoying to have a window pop up every time I do it.

What I really want is for it to do *nothing*, but all I can find is how to assign a different key combination to the command (which doesn't work in this case for some reason, it just adds it as a second shortcut in addition to ⌘W) or how to assign the key combination to a different command. Is there any way to disable the shortcut entirely instead?

Update: this seems to specifically be a problem with Microsoft Remote Desktop version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on MS RDC v10 but not the old v8.

Replacing Close  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  with a 'garbage' command effectively removes the hot key from the interface - though it doesn't make it work as Close Tab in Windows, it seems to just ignore it.
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  does close tabs [as expected].

[image]

Comment: I tried that, and it displays the new key combination in the menu but the old one still works as well.  Also, I don't know if it's related to the problem, but the command I'm seeing is "Close Connection," not "Close."

Comment: Ah, I see that now on the old version. Get the new one from the App Store - v10, which is not a direct upgrade from v8 but a new App.

Comment: Looks like that was it, I removed it and replaced it with v10 and now everything's fine.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer to cover that, thanks for checking.